# Python money denomination loop does not work on decimal

Tags: python

I am learning python and I what I need to achieve is to count how many denominations of 1000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1 , 0.25, 0.01 count base on my input data of **1575.78**.This specific code bums me out.

```
def withdraw_money():
denoms = (1000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10,5,1,.25,0.01)
while True:
    try:
        withdraw = 1575.770
        break
    except Exception as e:
        print('Incorrect input: %s' % e)
    

print("Here is the bill breakdown for the amount input")
for d in denoms:
    count = withdraw // d
    print('P%i = %i' % (d, count))
    withdraw -= count * d
 

withdraw_money()
```

My current output is:

```
Here is the bill breakdown for the amount input

P1000 = 1
P500 = 1
P200 = 0
P100 = 0
P50 = 1
P20 = 1
P10 = 0
P5 = 1
P1 = 0
P0.25 = 3
P0.01 = 2
```

which is wrong because the `P0.01 = 2` is suppose to be `P0.01 =3.`

However this code is correct when running whole numbers like 1500, or 20 but large number with decimal it get wrong on the 0.01 denomination count.

Comment: there is a lot of unclear stuff with this code: why do you define a function? Why there is a while true loop ? why do you need a try except for assigning a variable? Identation is also very funky...please explain the code a little bit better

Comment: @Indiano you are correct it lacks some requirements. I now edited it.

Comment: Why are you worried that `withdraw = 1575.78` might throw an exception?

Comment: @JohnGordon, I am confuse why the P0.01 value is outputting 2 while it is suppose to be 3.

Comment: I'm asking why you bothered with the `try/except` block.  It seems very strange.

Comment: @JohnGordon I'll remove that one. In my earlier version, it was an input field but for debugging purposes I hardcoded the withdraw as a static value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After debugging the code, I found the error. Using `round()` solve the problem.

```
def withdraw_money():
    denoms = (1000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10,5,1,0.25,0.01)
    while True:
        try:
            withdraw = 1575.77
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print('Incorrect input: %s' % e)
        
    print("Here is the bill breakdown for the amount input")
    for i in range(len(denoms)):
        if denoms[i] != 0.01: count = withdraw // denoms[i]
        else: count = withdraw / denoms[i]
        print(f'P{denoms[i]} = {count:0.0f}')
        withdraw = round(withdraw % denoms[i],2)
     

withdraw_money()
```

Comment: thanks for the help however, if I change the withdraw value from 1575.770 to 1575.71 or 1575.72 it will be wrong on the P0.01 demonination

Comment: @MiksMeister Woah! Interesting

Comment: @MiksMeister It's Solved. Check Now

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll improve much more on the decimal points

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use f string here like below

```py
def withdraw_money():
    denoms = (1000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1, .25, 0.01)
    while True:
        try:
            withdraw = 1575.770
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print('Incorrect input: %s' % e)

    print("Here is the bill breakdown for the amount input")
    for d in denoms:
        count = withdraw // d
        print(f'P{d} = {count:0.0f}')
        withdraw -= count * d


withdraw_money()
```

Output:

```
Here is the bill breakdown for the amount input
P1000 = 1
P500 = 1
P200 = 0
P100 = 0
P50 = 1
P20 = 1
P10 = 0
P5 = 1
P1 = 0
P0.25 = 3
P0.01 = 1
```

Comment: I am trying to run your code but I am getting error on the print f part? Do I need to import a library for this?

Comment: can you try now it's working fine for me

Comment: I am still getting a parse error when I run it on python sandbox https://pythonsandbox.com/code/pythonsandbox_u21032_2h2aOc4rAS0pEAPeaBfcKo9v_v0.py

Comment: I don't know why this error, check this url https://onecompiler.com/python/3yqf9scz9

Comment: Thanks for this however, the last row of the result is wrong. Instead of P0.01 = 1 that should be P0.01 = 2, I am not sure how and why it outputs 1 rather than 2.

Comment: for the given input the answer is correct you made changes to input then it will be wrong

Comment: For your input of 1575.770 If you add the breakdown together that will be 1576.76. P0.25 =3 that is 0.75 and then P0.01 =1 which adds up to .076